# MariaDB inconsistent comparison results between DOUBLE(10,2) and string

Tags: sql, mariadb, rounding-error

I'm searching a table for an exact match on an `amount` column `DOUBLE(10,2)`. Due to the database driver I'm using, I have to bind my amount as a string parameter. In general this works well, hoever this leads to certain values not being found.

For example, when comparing `3.94` to `'3.94'`:

```sql
SELECT CAST('3.94' AS DOUBLE(10,2)) = '3.94' `comp`, CAST('3.94' AS DOUBLE(10,2)) `cast`, '3.94' `string`;
```

The database considers them to be the same:

```
comp  cast  string
   1  3.94    3.94
```

However, when comparing `7.94` to `'7.94'`:

```sql
SELECT CAST('4.94' AS DOUBLE(10,2)) = '4.94' `comp`, CAST('4.94' AS DOUBLE(10,2)) `cast`, '4.94' `string`;
```

The database considers them to be different:

```
comp  cast  string
   0  4.94    4.94
```

In both cases, what I am being shown *looks like* the same value, even when they don't match. My presumption is that there is a rounding error going on somewhere but I don't fully understand the reason for the failure.

I would also like to know if there are any better/alternative solutions to resolve this other than:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `my_amounts_table`
WHERE
`amount` = CAST(:amount AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

---

**EDIT**

Apparently you should never do equality checks on floating point numbers.

In my above cases would I need to do something more like this to find values match `7.94`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `my_amounts_table`
WHERE
(`amount` > 7.93 AND `amount` < 7.95)
```

Comment: You should never search for floating point values by an exact value, as they often don't have an exact decimal representation. Always use a range or a rounding difference. And *never* search it using a string. See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/type-conversion.html If you need to cast, then cast it to the same type as the column.

Comment: Good to know and thank you for the link to the reference manual.

Comment: Take a look at https://float.exposed

Comment: That is an excellent resource! Thank you.

Comment: the mysql documentation is not a good resource for a mariadb question.

Comment: @ysth Problem is that the MariaDB is an even worse resource, this is not documented there at all. At least MariaDB is a fork of MySQL, so data types mostly behave the same.

Comment: yeah, but the mysql doc says decimal = string will convert both to floating, which is untrue at least for mariadb, and explicitly what needs to be avoided here

Comment: @TheImpaler both answers you downvoted *do* use ranges, just not apparently the way you like to.

Comment: @ysth I agree. As I see it it's much safer to have explicit range comparisons. An implicit one tends to be obscure and error prone.

Answer (score 1):

DOUBLE (and FLOAT) cannot represent most values exactly.  Use DECIMAL, which is designed to do so, instead:

```
SELECT
    CAST('4.94' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) = '4.94' `comp`,
    CAST('4.94' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) `cast`, '4.94' `string`;
```

Your column type should very likely be DECIMAL in the first place.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PQKtVing)

Comment: This is not a good answer. The comparison should use a number range, not equality.

Comment: @TheImpaler what case do you think that will improve?

Comment: @TheImpaler a number range is exactly what casting to a decimal type does.  https://dbfiddle.uk/NjQndPES

Answer (score 1):

When storing 'money', declare the column `DECIMAL(11,2)` (or some suitable size).  Then all these questions and discussions and `CASTs` and `ROUNDs` go away.  '3.94' *with or without quotes* stores the same and compares as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Consider also

```
ROUND('4.94', 2)
```

Or

```
FORMAT('4.94', 2)
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. The comparison should use a number range, not equality.